# How can I make a custom field with a formula that generates an MD5 hash?

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field

I'm trying to make a custom field that uses a formula to generate a hash by another field.

In short, the idea is: Use field partnerCode to generate a MD5 hash. Something like md5(partnerCode)

I've already seen Crypto.generateDigest, but it seems that formulas don't allow to call Apex classes and I have no idea how to join it :(

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: MD5 is [cryptographically broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security). Consider using a more modern hash algorithm.

Comment: Depending on your use case, using an [Encrypted Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm#!) may meet your requirement if you need to show hashed values to certain users and let privileged users see the original value. If not, then you _will_ need to use Apex as Derek F has pointed out. Formula fields don't have access to cryptographic functions.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done via formula field (or any of the other declarative tools we have such as workflow, flows, or process builder). The functions you can use with formula fields are documented in the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions.htm&type=5) page.

You'll need to write some Apex to accomplish this. It could be part of a trigger (this would be a good fit for a `before` trigger context) or as a class with an `@invocableMethod()` annotation for use with process builder.